# Google Firebase sign out and forget google account

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

Can someone help me, I'm learning java and is creating a basic sign-in/signup app.

The user can sign in, using their google account, with no issues and the same when signing up/in without a Google account.

When signing out without using their google account using their email etc, the app will forget the user, and another user can sign in. But when signing out using their google account, the app will remember the account, and when I go to sign back in, it will auto sign that google account back in.

I need some help, so the app will forget their Google account if they sign out, so someone else can sign in using their Google account.

Heres the code for the sign out page.
Cheers

```
package com.example.firebaseauthentication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    Button btn_signout;


    FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btn_signout = findViewById(R.id.btn_signout);

        btn_signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do you forget/sign out an google account, so another google account can sign in? without the app remembering the account you just signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you forget/sign out a Google account, so another google account can sign in?

To sign-out a Google account, please use the following lines of code:

```
GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(application.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

GoogleSignInClient googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(application, options);
googleClient.signOut();
```

If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check the following article:

- [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!